# localhost is not working but any oyher sites are ok

Tags: localhost

When I go to localhost:8000 (other ports too like 8080 or 8001) it responds error like: Can`t access localhost. And when I wanted to fix and diagnose net there was: "localhost is responding to access" Somethin like that     [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eO7PG.png)

Comment: Hey, can you check that your IDE / Terminal has enough privileges to access port?

Another area to look is your antivirus / firewall.